# CUDA Thrust Functor with Flexibility to Run in CPU or GPU

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, functor, thrust

This might be a stupid question, but I cannot seem to be able to find any resources specifically related to it, so your opinion is appreciated.

Let's say I have some functor

```
struct AddOne {
    thrust::device_ptr<int> numbers;

    __device__
    void operator()(int i) {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

that i can call from

```
AddOne addOneFunctor;
thrust::device_vector<int> idx(100), numbers(100);
addOneFunctor.numbers = numbers.data();
thrust::sequence(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
thrust::for_each(thrust::device, idx.begin(), idx.end(), addOneFunctor);
```

Is it is possible to write the above so that the execution policy can be changed at either compile-time or ideally run-time?

E.g. change the struct to

```
struct AddOne {
    thrust::pointer<int> numbers;

     __host__ __device__
     void operator()(int i) {
         numbers[i] = numbers[i] + 1;
     }
}
```

so it can be run something like

```
AddOne addOneFunctor;
std::vector<int> idx(100), numbers(100);
addOneFunctor.numbers = numbers.data();
thrust::sequence(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
thrust::for_each(thrust::cpp::par, idx.begin(), idx.end(), addOneFunctor);
```

The bottom line is: I would like to have a single code-base where I can decide to either use `thrust::device_vector`s or some sort of host vector (such as `std::vector`s) and run these in the GPU (using `thrust::device` exec policy) or CPU (using `thrust::cpp::par` or similar policy) respectively.

PS: I would like to avoid PGI for now.

Comment: you do not have to specify the execution policy when using device / host vectors, thrust infers the execution policy automatically based on the the iterator type.

Comment: Both answers below are nice, but I can't check both ... sorry

Comment: You can upvote both.

Comment: I don't have the reputation yet, but it'll update when I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, pretty much exactly as you describe.

Here's a fully-worked example:

```
$ cat t1205.cu
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct AddOne {
    int *numbers;
     template <typename T>
     __host__ __device__
     void operator()(T &i) {
         numbers[i] = numbers[i] + 1;
     }
};

int main(){

  AddOne addOneFunctor;
  std::vector<int> idx(100), numbers(100);
  addOneFunctor.numbers = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(numbers.data());
  thrust::sequence(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
  thrust::for_each(thrust::cpp::par, idx.begin(), idx.end(), addOneFunctor);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    std::cout << numbers[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  thrust::device_vector<int> didx(100), dnumbers(100);
  addOneFunctor.numbers = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dnumbers.data());
  thrust::sequence(didx.begin(), didx.end(), 0);
  thrust::for_each(thrust::device, didx.begin(), didx.end(), addOneFunctor);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    std::cout << dnumbers[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1205 t1205.cu
$ ./t1205
1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
$
```

Note that the algorithim is `thrust::sequence` not `thrust::seq`.

Using CUDA 8RC

As @m.s. points out, the explict use of the execution policies on the algorithms for the codes above are not necessary - you can remove those and it will work the same way.  However the formal usage of execution policy allows the above example to be extended to the case where you are not using containers, but ordinary host and device data, so it may still have some value, depending on your overall goals.

Comment: Many thanks! ... and you're right, it's thrust::sequence, my bad

Comment: My ultimate question is though: how could I build the code to switch between either one or the other at compile time or run time? Is it possible to do this at runtime without using if statements?

Comment: @A.I. no, you can't switch at runtime "without if statements"; you could write generic template functions with the vector as the template parameter and by passing either a device vector or a host vector you can choose at compile time

Answer (score 1):

Would this fit your requirement?

1. Always use `thrust::device_vector` to run on device;
2. Define different macros on compile time to select the device to be GPU or CPU (OpenMP/TBB/CPP).

More info here:

https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Device-Backends

Comment: Thanks. I thought about using macros for this, but is there a way to choose between the desired type at runtime?

Comment: A same algorithm can be applied to both device and host vectors at the same time as in Robert Crovella's code. So choosing the desired type means at least you have to copy the data to the desired place manually. No automatic way.